# Joining Excel to attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, database-design

Im working with ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap), trying to create a geodatabase.
So I have a bunch of coordinate points to create polygons and an excel full of attribute data about those polygons.

What methods could I follow to join both? Or getting the Excel info into the attribute table as quick and automatized as possible?

1. The data in the Excel has the same columns structure than the empty attribute tables on the features in the geodatabase.
2. I know there's a function to join the Excel to a shapefile correlating both with a particular ID, but unless Im wrong, this seems to not be permanent. I want something permanent.
3. It would be ideal to have a method I could use directly on the geodatabase, but I guess I could also work on a shapefile and then just paste the polygons on the geodatabase if that way is better.

Is there any method that could work for me?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Have you tried Excel To Table to import your rows?

Comment: Fist convert your Excel to a file geodatabase table, Excel spreadsheets are notoriously flaky. How is it you create your polygons from your points? I get the impression that there is at least one field that is common for both polygons and table, if that's the case then Join Field (ArcMAP: https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000, ArcGIS Pro: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm ) makes the join permanent.

Comment: @PolyGeo Arcgis desktop/Arcmap

Comment: @MichaelStimson Indeed Im keeping an OBJECTID column with the same number in both the shapefile and the excel table. Ill try this method and see if it adjust to what Im want, thanks.